# having problems with my js external file with html

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a slider on my home page and a hamburger nav and font size change in one file, however. they do not all work unless i split them into different files. Why is this? can someone explain please?

I have added the external file link to each of my pages, if i were to take the script out and out it straight into the html it will work. So as i am new to this it is probably so simple and i apologise if this is a stupid question.

see the js file below;

```js
///NAV

document.querySelector(".toggle-button").addEventListener("click", () => 
{
  document.querySelector("#nav").classList.toggle("hide")
})


//FONT SIZE

document.getElementById("smallA").onclick = function(){changeSize("small")};

document.getElementById("mediumA").onclick = function(){changeSize("medium")};

document.getElementById("largeA").onclick = function(){changeSize("large")};

function changeSize(c)
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className= c;
}






//SLIDER

let slideIndex = 0;
      showSlides();

      function showSlides() {
        let i;
        let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
          slideIndex = 1;
        }

        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
      }
```

Comment: In what was does the code "not work" and what debugging have you done?  If you're not familiar with your browser's development tools, now is the time to start.  you can observe errors on the console, observe network requests/responses for page resources, even use the script debugger to step through the code as it executes and observe its behaviors and results.  When you do this, what specific problem do you find?  Can you replicate that problem in a [mcve] in the question above, or provide more specific information about that problem?

Comment: The way your script is written, it has to be imported only *after* the rest of your page (the HTML body) has been read by the browser. If you import a single script with all of the code in your question with a `<script>` tag at the very end of the `<body>`, it will be able to find all the elements searched for.

Comment: We can only *assume* you have a line with `<script src='myscript.js'></script>`.  Is the filename correct?  Is the path to the .js correct?  (confirm these by replacing the js file with a one liner `alert("myscript")` (in the js)).   Exactly how do you include the js - [edit] the question and include the `<script src=` line - if this is malformed, the browser won't load the js.

Comment: I had to use 2 external js files, as it wouldn't work with them all in...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/scripts.js" defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.js" defer></script>

Comment: Everything works fine now i separated the Nav code out, however i am still getting errors in regarding cannot find document, I will look into this in more detail, thank you David

Comment: If your code uses jquery (provided code doesn't appear to) then make sure jquery.js is first - generally make sure jquery.js is first anyway.

Comment: Ok thanks, if I dropped my toggle nav code for hamburger and my font sizing code in the same file it didn't work? As both need to be there from the start? Is this why it would have been a problem?

Comment: @Pointy so I should add all at the end of the body rather than I'm the head?

Comment: Look, with what you've posted it's really hard to tell what the various problems might be. Combining or not combining code *can* make a difference if you're using the module system, but I don't see evidence in your code. Plain old JavaScript affects the global context, so being in one file or 10 files should not matter *unless* your script code requires DOM elements to have been created before it runs. That's what putting the code at the end of the `<body>` does to help make things work.